# symfony - custom multiple checkbox widget - help

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I'm trying to create a custom multiple choice  checkbox widget, that displays all items of a model.

My model is named 'Tag', which is a list of tags in my DB table.

I have copied the sfWidgetFormSelectCheckbox code and pasted it into my new widget class, but I'm unsure what to do next

Could someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Why `sfWidgetFormSelectCheckbox` is not working for you?

Comment: This is pretty much the question you asked yesterday: [symfony - embeddedForm - mulitple checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805591/symfony-embeddedform-mulitple-checkboxes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working using some custom code, i.e. getters and setters and overriding the doUpdateObject() and updateDefaultsFromObject methods in my form class

Answer (score 1):

If your issue is working with tags. Best to look at [sfDoctrineActAsTaggable](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineActAsTaggablePlugin). It should have all the behaviour you require, hence you should be able to dissect it to achieve what you are after.